# How to test if a float number is even?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a one-dimensional array with float numbers. How can I find out the number of even elements?

Because it contains float elements, I can't use the condition `if (v[i] % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: What's your definition - is e.g. 4.567 even or odd?

Comment: Is 2.00000000000000001 even? What about 2.1?

Comment: what does it mean for a `float` to be "even" ? Do you mean `123.123` is odd while `122.123` is considered as even?

Comment: yes, it's like in the example you give

Comment: Read first http://floating-point-gui.de/ - it might happen that `123.123` is not representable exactly in [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). See [these slides](https://calcul.math.cnrs.fr/attachments/evt/2019-06-precision-num/support11.pdf)

Comment: Maybe you misinterpret the assignment. Do you perhaps need to select all the elements at even *indices*? That would seems more logical.

Comment: Three people asked you questions about the definition of “even” for this post, and you answered “yes, it's like in the example you give.” That does not tell readers which person you were answering. Answer each question specifically, identifying the question you are answering or stating the answer in enough detail to provide identification and/or state a clear definition that answers all of the questions.

Comment: Incidentally, if the definition of “even” is that the last non-zero decimal digit is even (0, 2, 4, 6, or 8), then no non-integer binary floating-point number is even. They all have the same last digit, 5.

Answer (score 5):

There are no even floating point numbers. Or rather: There is no widely accepted definition of what an "even floating point number" is. Of course that doesn't mean that you can't come up with your own definition that might be useful in some context. It seems you want to check if the integer part of a float number is even. That is:

```
float x = 3.1415;
int y = x;
if (y % 2 == 0) { /* y is even */ }
```

or shorter:

```
if (static_cast<int>(x) % 2 == 0) { /* x is "even" */ }
```

Comment: I prefer my answer as this one could generate overflows.

Comment: @Bathsheba The suggestions do wildly different things, so cannot be compared like that.

Comment: @Bathsheba if you're worried about overflows, you can do `!fmodf(floorf(x),2)`, kind of like in your answer, but satisfying OP's requirements.

Comment: `int y = x;` fails when `x` outside `int` range.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili  `!fmodf(floorf(x),2)` differs from this answer when x  = -41.9.  `trunc()` rather than `floor()` makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

(For the mathematicians out there, the set of `float`s - ignoring NaN, +Inf, -Inf  - represents a subset of the set of real numbers. Natural numbers are also a subset of the real numbers, and even numbers a subset of that too. Talking in terms of even numbers being a subset of real numbers makes sense too. Therefore the concept of an even `float` is a valid one.)

For a `float f` you can use reliably use `std::fmodf` and check that is non-zero. In other words,

```
!std::fmodf(f, 2.0f)
```

is a good test. I've taken care to avoid explicit conversions to integral types due to the pitfalls of undefined overflow.

---

The above uses a more natural definition of evenness than a truncation would give. If you want the evenness or otherwise to be a function of the non-decimal part of `f` then use

```
!std::fmodf(std::truncf(x), 2.0f)
```

as the test.

Comment: The OP specifically said they want `122.123` to be considered even. They only want to consider the whole number part. This answer does not achieve that.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Well that's a very curious definition of evenness. I'll leave this answer up as I like it.

Comment: Well, parity is usually considered to be a property strictly of integers (Even = {2k : k ∈ ℤ}, Odd = {2k + 1 : k ∈ ℤ}). So, to be honest, your interpretation is just as "curious". ;) But, as largest_prime pointed out, picking a definition for such a thing is largely in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: "Talking in terms of even numbers being a subset of real numbers makes sense too." Yes, but one should strictly distinguish between mathematical set properties and the according language referred/implementation depending representation mappings. And since the standard itself does not force a full integer compatibility to floating points (even IEEE 754 doesn't that fully), one should be careful to build things and solutions around this assumption, admitting though that it fits for most real world scenarios.

Comment: @Bathsheba, to make things clear: My point was quite generally stated, also referring to the OP. I also appreciate, that you circumvent the conversion overflow issue with your approach.

Comment: `represents a subset of the set of real numbers.` You can be more precise: They represent a subset of rational numbers. No irrational number is representable.

Answer (score 2):

Parity is defined for integer types only.

One way of doing it is casting each of `v[i]` to an integer variable and check it accordingly.

```
int val = static_cast<int>(v[i]);
if (val & 1) {
   // val is odd
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<int>(v[i])` is a problem when `v[i]` outside `int` range.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the tip, your answer and Bathsheba's will work best.

Answer (score 2):

> How to test if a float number is even?

Given OP's reply [it's like in the example you give](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702817/how-to-test-if-a-float-number-is-even/65704463?noredirect=1#comment116167064_65702817) to
[Do you mean 123.123 is odd while 122.123 is considered as even?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702817/how-to-test-if-a-float-number-is-even/65704463?noredirect=1#comment116167027_65702817)
OP wants to drop the fractional portion<sup>1</sup> of the `float` for even-ness consideration.

Extract the remainder with `fmod(x, 2)` and compare to 1.

```
if (fabs(fmod(v[i], 2)) < 1) {
    number_of_even_elements++;
}
```

- Avoid converting to some integer type as the result is not defined outside that integer type's range.
- Consider negative values.
- Also consider `INFINITY` and `NAN`.  The above returns `false`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> ... or possible round.  I'll go forward with *truncate*.

<sup>2</sup> `fmod(NAN,2), fmod(INFINITE,2)` often nicely return `NAN`. Then `fabs(fmod(v[i], 2)) < 1` nicely returns `false` for these exceptional cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, because there are no odd or even floating point numbers to begin with.

Comment: 0 is an even float number

Comment: 0 is not a floating point number. 0.0 is one...

Comment: Sure, but 0.0 is an even float number

Comment: And also -0.0 :)

Comment: 0 is a floating-point number, per IEEE 754-2008. “0” and “0.0” are numerals, and they represent the same number. Mathematicians define a number to be even iff it is an integral multiple of two, so all `float` values that are integral multiples of two are even (in the mathematical sense; OP may want something different).