# Having trouble studying for c++ exam, cant figure out this puzzle

Tags: c++

This is the question:

> Write a full program that allows the user to input five floating-point values. The program should find the sum of the numbers that are even. For example, if the values 12, 15, 3, 5, & 10 are inputted, then the value 22 will be displayed since 12 & 10 are even and their sum is 22. You can assume that all the inputted values will be greater than zero.

This is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float numOne = 0;
    float numTwo = 0;
    float numThree = 0;
    float numFour = 0;
    float numFive = 0;
    float evenSum = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the first number";
    cin >> numOne;
    cout << "Please enter the second number";
    cin >> numTwo;
    cout << "Please enter the third number";
    cin >> numThree;
    cout << "Please enter the fourth number";
    cin >> numFour;
    cout << "Please enter the fifth number";
    cin >> numFive;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's more a math question at this point. There is no even or odd in floating point. There isn't even Zuul.

Comment: Sorta-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65702817/4581301

Comment: The floating-point requirement make it a lot harder, especially since any number with decimal can't be either odd nor even.

Comment: Side note: when you have a bunch of sequentially named or numbered variables most of the time your job will be a LOT easier with an array and some loops.

Comment: With that said, if there are no decimals then you can convert it to an integer and use the modulo operator `%` to find out if it's odd or even. It will be a lot easier if you use arrays and loops, as then you don't need to repeat a lot of code.

Comment: Watch out when converting to integers. Some large numbers will get fuzzy around the edges and may not convert quite the way you'd expect.

Comment: Remember that this is *not* a free code writing service.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with `std::ranges`, so ignoring the `float` requirement was a nice bit of practice for me, at least. Could have basically one-lined it, but I don't think `std::ranges::fold_left` is officially supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

The task at hand is to find the sums of all the numbers the user enters that are even. We can do this by using the modulus operator (`%`). It gives us the remainder of a division. So, this code should work:

```
if (numOne % 2 == 0){
    // Do whatever
}
```

I would suggest then adding `numOne` to `evenSum`, and at the end, print out `evenSum`.